# I need to know what kind of tags now use in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I need to know what tags are now use in jsp? I heard that using scrip-lets is not a good practice.Please suggest be tags to learn with jsp.

Answer (score 3):

The common practice is using JSTL library in the place of scriptlets, and really  it covers various operations like iterating and conditionals.

link for reference: https://jstl.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the free online book http://pdf.coreservlets.com. But the answer is not black & white: the JSP standard is designed so you can create your own tags, so there is no distinct set of tags to refer to. You can probably download plenty of third party taglibs from the net.